# Unsubscribing Users from Firebase Emails

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

In my Firebase application I have several [`Cloud Functions`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) that send emails to users when they perform certain actions.

I would like to embed a link on each email that has an `unsubscribe` option users can select so they will no longer be notified; similar to many emails you receive in your inbox.

I searched through Firebase's documentation but can't locate a specific setting for disabling this per user, so my first thought is to add a flag in the `Realtime Database` for each user that might click `unsubscribe`. When the function is triggered I would then have to fetch the given user and check for the flag which would determine whether to send the email or not.

Is there a common solution to handle this scenario, or is this the only way? Any input is appreciated!

Comment: There is no built-in way to do this, and what you proposed sounds reasonable. Good luck with it!

Comment: What you proposed sounds the way to go to me too. The only flag that is built in would be "emailVerified" which doesn't help here. Just curious, what service are you using for sending the emails? I'm trying to set up mine. Cheers

Comment: @TheeBen @Michael thanks guys! @TheeBen here's the example I built off of - it's utilizes`nodemailer` https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users